# What is the best way to test a REST API for backwards compatibility?

Tags: json, api, rest, backwards-compatibility

My goal is to come up with a set of automated tests that will consume some services of an API and check if the compatibility is not broken (by mistake or on purpose).

My initial idea is to get the JSON results and deserialize against the DTOs used in the serialization. The reason is to avoid the manual generation of a schema that can get really big and difficult to maintain. The problem is that libraries like GSON are very robust and tend not to thrown exceptions when some problem happens in the deserialization (unless we write a custom deserializer, that again will take time and maintainance efforts).

Am I going in the right direction here? or is there another way to ensure API compatibility?

(Ideally, I would like to test not only JSON, but also XML responses from the same API.)

Comment: What am I missing? It sounds like you're comparing the (current) DTO to the (current) JSON results. That just checks if the serialization/deserialization worked. It doesn't do anything for the backwards compatibility of the business logic.

Comment: @EricStein Maybe I did not explain it in enough details. Let us suppose we release the API on certain day and we use version 1.0 of the DTO. I will use this version in my compatibility tests, and check the current JSON results against the DTO v1.0 to see if everything is properly deserialized, or if exceptions are thrown (which would mean the compatibility is probably broken). Does it make sense to you?